# SOHO vs Enterprise AP for Network Interference

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I only have elementary knowledge of networking and I am hoping you all can shed some light on my issue. I currently am running an Airport Extreme (N and AC) and I noticed sometimes the wifi speeds slow down considerably. At some points it's near unusable. It's not even a considerable distance. My devices that are about 20 feet away in another room from the router starts to buffer constantly. I check the wired connection and it's running very quickly. I have tried using another wireless router, ASUS N router, but it suffers from the same issue.

I think the problem is the number of other networks that is around my apartment. I see at least 20 other networks. I have thought about going the wired solution, but it's simply too expensive to wire the apartment with ethernet.

I am wondering will Enterprise APs perform better in this situation than SOHO routers? I was looking into Ubiquiti UAP-Pro to try to solve the issue.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of wifi card are you using?  What kind of computer?  Are you using 2.4G or 5G wifi?

Comment: Both 2.4 and 5 are enabled but I believe it's mostly using the 5

Comment: Please set up your airport for [5g only](http://www.yourdailymac.net/2011/05/how-to-activate-450-mbps-wi-fi-on-your-2011-spec-macbook-pro-or-imac/) and let me know whether this improves the situation.

Comment: @MikePennington would that make a difference? I have my airport setup on different SSIDs for 5g vs 2.5. I experience the issue on both bands. Not to mention 5G has reallllly short range

Comment: I think you're underestimating how far you can throw 5G.  I build industrial wifi solutions, and it will go through a sheetrock wall without problems... not as well as 2.4G, but good enough.  Anyway... this is the joy of wifi, you never really know what the problem is unless you try 20 different things, or find someone who can run diagnostics

Comment: @MikePennington I probably am underestimating. It has just been disappointing that on 2.4G or 5G I get times where loading a webpage takes a decade. I do agree 5G does perform better, but it seems like it happens on both bands. But going back to my original question, do you think Enterprise APs can perform better under conditions with heavy interference? I noticed I mostly get these slow downs ~dinner time/night where I am guessing OTA netflix traffic is high or something.

Comment: With basically no evidence beyond your personal observations, it sounds like co channel interference... Check whether there are unused channels with something like WiFi Analyzer on Android.  Probably you have multiple 802.11ac APs hogging airtime which means your best options are a wire, or moving to a lesser popular location